# Converting to JSTL (Specificlly on calling methods)

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, porting, scriptlet

I'm in the process of going the full JSTL way, and I've got an issue with the following scriplet, I have already transformed the variable displaying and conditions to the expression language (EL) but I'm not so sure of how to do it with method calling : here's my JSP code its positioned before the html markup:

            `UserDTO user = (UserDTO) session.getAttribute("user");`

```
        OrderDAO lnkOrder = new OrderDAO();
        OrderDTO order = new OrderDTO();

        CoverDAO lnkCover = new CoverDAO();
        CoverDTO cover = new CoverDTO();

        UpgradesDAO lnkUpgrades = new UpgradesDAO();
        UpgradesDTO upgrades = new UpgradesDTO();

        OrderAccessorieDAO lnkOrderAcc = new OrderAccessorieDAO();
        List<OrderAccessorieDTO> orderAccessories = new ArrayList<OrderAccessorieDTO>();

        GroupColorsDAO lnkColors = new GroupColorsDAO();
        List<ColorDTO> ColorList = new ArrayList<ColorDTO>();
        ColorList = lnkColors.getGroupColors(user.getGroup());

        AccessoryDAO lnkAcc = new AccessoryDAO();
        List<AccessoryDTO> groupAccessories = new ArrayList<AccessoryDTO>();
        groupAccessories = lnkAcc.getGroupAccessories(user.getGroup());

        ChangesDAO lnkChanges = new ChangesDAO();
        List<ChangeDTO> orderChanges = new ArrayList<ChangeDTO>();

        String CurrentOrder = request.getParameter("CurrentOrder");

        if (lnkOrder.exists(CurrentOrder)) {
            order = lnkOrder.find(CurrentOrder);
            cover = lnkCover.find(order.getReferenceNumber());
            upgrades = lnkUpgrades.find(order.getReferenceNumber());
            orderAccessories = lnkOrderAcc.getOrderAccessories(order.getReferenceNumber());
            orderChanges = lnkChanges.getOrderChanges(order.getReferenceNumber());
        }
```

As yo can see it's pretty much DAO and DTO objects, I know that it can be done using static methods and making custom taglibs but that would mean writing a code for each method call, any other approach?, suggestions accepted. A brief description of the `VIEW`(HTML markup) it displays the details of a given order, the order name is extracted from a `get` request.

Also I have another small question, suppose I port everything to JSTL, would I have to import the corresponding `myDTO` and `myDAO` packages to access its getters and setters for each DTO?

Regards Tristian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"JSTL way" doesn't make sense without full separation between view and logic, as in [Model 2 approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2).

In Model 2 approach you move this code to the servlet that acts as a controller for your JSTL page, and only use JSP for view markup. Otherwise using JSTL to enforce separation between logic and view with JSTL would be meaningless.

Comment: In a sense what your saying is that I should perform the method calls in a controller (suppose `OrderDetails.java`) and then forward the response to the JSTL/HTML page?

Comment: Thanks, great diagram by the way.(The wikipedia link.)

Answer (score 0):

The only work around (dirty) that I know is to expose the methods as a fake map, that is have a method that has a sig like "Object getSomething(Object o)". In this way you can pass an argument, and it gets around the imposed rules. Fugly but it works.

Agree with axtavt though